# OWA kicks user out within seconds of authenticating

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8.1, internet-explorer

Issue exists for all users at a specific location.

Users accessing same system at other locations do NOT get the same issue.

When kicked out, there is no error, OWA dumps the user back at the login screen.

Issue has been replicated on Chrome, IE, Edge, and Firefox.

Cookie handling is WIDE OPEN.

HTTP and HTTPS are unrestricted by the Firewall in the Router.

Any advice would be Very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have access to the Exchange Server. The client is using hosted Exchange from a third party vendor. This vendor is not Office 365. Users are able to connect to OWA from outside the office.  Whatever this is, it is definitely related to the local network.

Comment: If users from outside the office doesn't experience the same issue, it's an issue isolated in the local network. Perhaps, there could be drop packets that you can test from the local network. Using wireshark or other network capturing tools